# Ordering strings in an array according to number in string

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, integer

I'm trying to order strings in an array depending on the number present in them, ie. 'h2ello f3ere b1ow' should return an array of ['b1ow', 'h2ello' ,' f3ere']. The following code works with two elements (h2ello and b1ow), but not when I add a third. Does anyone have an idea why this is?

```
function order(words){
  var sentence = [];
  words = words.split(" ");
 for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
   for (var m=0;m<words[i].length;m++){
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(words[i][m])) && isFinite(words[i][m])){
     var idx = words[i][m];
         sentence.splice(idx, 0, words[i]);
     }
   }
 }
 console.log(sentence);
}

order('h2ello f3ere b1ow');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check documentation on splice: [Array splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you will see that if index is longer than the length of the array, it will be set to the length of the array. So its just doing a push instead of setting at the index you want. One solution could be setting it manually:

```
sentence[idx-1] = words[i]
```

Depending on your needs you could also simplify your function quite a bit:

```
function order(words){
  words = words.split(" ").sort(function(a,b){
    return a.match(/\d/) -  b.match(/\d/) // get first digit and compare them
  })
 console.log(words);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be the direct sort of the array, without splicing to a place where the other places are unknown (in the loop).

This proposal uses [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a callback which looks for some decimal to sort for.

```js
var array = 'h2ello f3ere b1ow'.split(' ');

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.match(/\d+/) - b.match(/\d+/);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which has better performance. BTW mine has one less regex match per comparison.

```js
var sorted = 'h2ello f3ere b1ow'.split(' ')
  .map(w => ({ key: w.match(/\d+/)[0], word: w }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key)
  .map(o => o.word).join(' ');

console.log(sorted);
```